# Text Doesn't Display in List - TypeError

Tags: javascript

I'm a JavaScript beginner, and I am having trouble with a simple todo list. When the button is clicked, it should invoke the `todoList` function, and add the item onto the unordered list. Here's my html code:

```js
    function todoList(){
      var item = document.getElementById('todoInput').value
      var text = document.createTextNode(item)
      var newItem = document.createElement('li')
      newItem.appendChild(text)
      document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(newItem)
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>To Do List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>To Do List</h1>
        <form id="todoForm">
          <input id="todoInput">
          <button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Add Task</button>
        </form>
        <ul id="todoList">
        </ul>
        <script type="text/javasript" src="index.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

And this is my todoList function.

When I enter an item and click on the button, I get an uncaught typeError in the console. What did I do wrong here?

[image]

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal in another file called `index.js`

@Adriani6 still doesn't work even when I placed it in the head tag

Comment: Wrap it by `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', yourFunction, false);`

Comment: @Pusheenicorn you have a typo  `type="text/javasript"`  should be `type="text/javascript"` Check spelling of script

Answer (score -1):

This will work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
function todoList(){
  var item = document.getElementById('todoInput').value
  var text = document.createTextNode(item)
  var newItem = document.createElement('li')
  newItem.appendChild(text)
  document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(newItem)
}
</script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>To Do List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <form id="todoForm">
      <input id="todoInput">
      <button type="button" onclick="todoList()">Add Task</button>
    </form>
    <ul id="todoList">
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```